# Not getting API response data from web API in React Native

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api, react-redux

I am using fetch function in React Native to call ASP.NET web API to get list of data in a JSON format. The response which I am getting from API is 200 (ok). But I am not getting the actual data. If I ran the same URL in Postman I am getting the data which I am expecting.

For example, I am running http://192.168.1.5:8082/api/ECommerce/GetCategory URL in GET method. If I am running the above URL in Postman I am getting the data which I expected.

[image]

If I am using the same URL in fetch function in React Native and console the response now I am getting the following:

[image]

I am not getting the list of data.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you use to fetch data with Fetch API or Axios?

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel fetch return promise..you need to resolve it by using  ```.json()``` ```fetch(URL)
      .then(result=> result.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });```